# Can not import Commons DbUtils in Maven2

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm trying to add Commons DbUtils to Maven2 but I'm getting this problem:

> Missing artifact commons-dbutils:commons-dbutils:jar:1.6

How can I import it?

My pom.xml:

```
        **<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBUtils 1.6 isn't in the main MVN repo by the looks of things.

The reason for this is that the latest version appears to be 1.5!

See:
http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/download_dbutils.cgi

Try this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much :). 1.5 version is OK :).

Comment: @user1819402 Glad it worked. If you could accept the answer, that'd be great.